# Partially apply the infix operator with map

Tags: haskell, infix-notation, infix-operator

I have the following function g

```
g :: Int -> Int -> Int 
g x y = x + y * y
```

I use g in the following three ways but don't quite understand what they each do.

```
map (g 10)  [1,2,3,4,5] -- 1

map (10 ‘g‘) [1,2,3,4,5] -- 2

map (‘g‘ 10) [1,2,3,4,5] -- 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x `g` y
```

is defined on [haskell.org](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sections) as

```
x `g` y = g x y
```

This results in the following for

```
-- 1
map (g 10) [1,2,3,4,5] ==
map (\x -> g 10 x) [1,2,3,4,5]

-- 2
map (10 `g`) [1,2,3,4,5] ==
map (\x -> g 10 x) [1,2,3,4,5]

-- 3
map (`g` 10) [1,2,3,4,5] ==
map (\x -> g x 10) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I hope this made it a bit more clear.

Comment: `x \`g\` y = \x y -> g x y` is incorrect; it is actually `x \`g\` y = g x y`

Comment: Is `\x y -> g x y` not equivalent to `g x y`?

Comment: @joelfischerr If `g` takes two arguments, I think the first one is a function the second is a value.

Comment: @joelfischerr It is not equivalent. If `g :: A -> B -> C`, then `x \`g\` y :: C`, and `(\x y -> x \`g\` y) :: A -> B -> C`.

Comment: @joelfischerr No. `\x y -> g x y` is the same as (for example) `\a b -> g a b`, which is not equivalent to `g x y` for the same reason.

Comment: @joelfischerr, However, `\x y -> g x y` *is* equivalent to `g`   (if you ignore that nasty `seq` pedantry).  Maybe that is what you were thinking of.

Comment: @luqui Yes that is what I was thinking of. Thanks!